# Raspberry Pi 2B gets IP and then drops it - Buster

Tags: ethernet, dhcp, ipv6

Having a weird issue, my RPi 2 B starts to get an ipv6 on my network and then for some reason proceeds to drop it.

```
....
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[290]: Registering new address record for fe80::3f7e:2be8:86af:8175 on enxb827eb1bec22.*.
......
May 30 08:21:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: no IPv6 Routers available
```

I have tried rebooting it, setting IPv6 to disabled in sysctl.conf

`net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`

Has anyone seen a solution to this issue? It's somewhat of a show stopper for my use case.

```
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi kernel: smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 enxb827eb1bec22: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: IAID eb:1b:ec:22
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: adding address fe80::3f7e:2be8:86af:8175
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[290]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enxb827eb1bec22.IPv6 with address fe80::3f7e:2be8:86af:8175.
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[290]: New relevant interface enxb827eb1bec22.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[290]: Registering new address record for fe80::3f7e:2be8:86af:8175 on enxb827eb1bec22.*.
May 30 08:21:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 30 08:21:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 30 08:21:10 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: probing for an IPv4LL address
May 30 08:21:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: using IPv4LL address 169.254.234.60
May 30 08:21:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
May 30 08:21:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: adding default route
May 30 08:21:15 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[290]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enxb827eb1bec22.IPv4 with address 169.254.234.60.
May 30 08:21:15 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[290]: New relevant interface enxb827eb1bec22.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 30 08:21:15 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[290]: Registering new address record for 169.254.234.60 on enxb827eb1bec22.IPv4.
May 30 08:21:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[361]: enxb827eb1bec22: no IPv6 Routers available
May 30 08:22:08 raspberrypi sudo[447]:       pi : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
```

Comment: fe80 is a link local address. Apparently the Pi does not find any IPv6 routers to communicate with. If you look at the output of `ifconfig -a`, is the IPv6 address still there? It normally should not be a showstopper for anything; why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: Soo I feel foolish. Check connections :D Wire was unplugged at hub downstream :P

Answer (score 2):

User error :P Hub unplugged downstream.

So my Raspberry Pi was connected to the a switch, that switch was connected to the wall jack, going to the network closet in the house. It was unplugged there at the router.

Comment: I do not understand. What does it mean?

Comment: So my Raspberry Pi was connected to the a switch, that switch was connected to the wall jack, going to the network closet in the house. It was unplugged there at the router.